# Lion server change hostname always pointing to host name for internet

Tags: dns, osx-lion

I am new to Lion server setup. A static IP has been configured in Lion server, but we don't have domain name to assign for this static IP. So we planned to keep this for internal use.

When i try to configure Host name (Server -> Network -> HostName -> Edit) it is always pointing to "Host name for internet" option. But i need to "Host name for local Address".[Please find the attached screen shot]

[image]

It is not reflecting after i changed to "Host name for local Address".

Due to this reason i am not able to access "Local Web Server".  I started the Web server service  (Server -> Web -> ON). After that i tried to access default web (https://myIpAddress) it is not working.

What do i need to do in order to access local web server in Lion server?

Answer (score 0):

Edit your /etc/hosts file with an alias for your localhost.

You don't want to use the GUI for this.